# MS Word field brackets

Tags: ms-word

So, I have a word document (template) with fields (DocVaariables) that are filled up with data coming from a db.

I really know nothing about MS Word, fields and embedded xml, however I figured out how to insert generic field in my document, but when I do so they don't look like the ones already in it.

This is what I can insert myself:

```
{DOCVARIABLE "InvSecAmountLine2"}
```

And this is how the existing ones look like:

```
[{DOCVARIABLE "InvSecAmountLine2"}]
```

I don't know how to reproduce those brackets and when I use the field without them, the values no longer appears in preview/print.

Also:
I can't format these fields (The options in the field panel are disabled) and the switch formatting doesn't not work as well.

Can anyone help me with this or refer me to a useful link I can have a look at?

Comment: Some questions: What version of Word are you using? How are you inserting the DOCVARIABLE (via VBA, .NET, manually into the document)? Why does your DOCVARIABLE have quotation marks (typically the variable does not)? I have never seen square brackets used programmatically for a DOCVARIABLE, which is typically used to insert variable information via VBA or .NET. Are you using any third-party libraries to automate the data within the Word files? Can you link to a Word document file that contains hard-coded data in which the DOCVARIABLE works correctly when used with square brackets?

Comment: Hi, I'm entering DOCVARIABLE manually from the toolbar. I don't know why the quotation marks are there, it works though.  I'm not using any third-party library and the version my MS-Word verision is the 2010. I don't understand the last question.

Comment: If all you want to do is create the special brackets manually, that's CTRL-F9 in Word. Please upload the document, link to it in your post and supply further information if you need additional assistance.